# global thread stops when device locked

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

In swift, I need to have a thread running even when the device is locked. I tried the code below but the loop is stopping as soon as the device gets locked:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
                while true {
                    print("thread running")
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
                }
            }
```

If the loop runs on the main thread, it doesn't stop, but it makes unlocking the device impossible (as the main thread deals with user interaction). Any hint on how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1

Comment: Or better: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW1

"The Background Transition Cycle"